# Prove $1/(1 − f)$ is convex on $[a,b]$, given $f$ is convex on $[a, b]$, $f'' $ exist on $(a, b)$, and $f < 1$ for all $x ∈ [a, b]$.

Tags: calculus

I tried to start from converting convexity of f into $1/(1-f) \le1/(1-(1-t)f(x)-tf(y))$, and go from there, but I don't seem to get anywhere. I saw there are some proofs about reciprocals of convex functions being convex with some conditions, which seem relevant, but I can't find a way to apply them in my proof either. I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: If $f$ is convex and $h$ is convex and increasing then $h \circ f$ is convex. – Alternatively, compute the second derivative of $1/(1-f)$, it is not difficult to see that it is positive.

Comment: given $f''$ exists why don't you just use the derivative definition of convexity? ... ah because $g''$  need not exist for $g = \frac1{1-f}$ like what xpaul is doing?

Comment: @MartinR Maybe OP's trying to do without using that $g'' \ge 0$ iff $g$ convex i.e. use the original definition of convex? Oh in this case instead of use original definition, you're suggesting to show $\frac1{1-x}$ is convex increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint：Try to calculate $(1/(1-f))’’$ and determine its sign.

In fact,
$$ \bigg(\frac1{1-f(x)}\bigg)’’=\frac{2(f’(x))^2+(1-f(x))f’’(x)}{(1-f(x))^3} \ge0 $$
which means it is convex since $f’’(x)\ge0$.

Comment: Maybe OP's trying to do without using that $g'' \ge 0$ iff $g$ convex i.e. use the original definition of convex?

Comment: Since $f$ is given to be twice differentiable, it is better to take derivative.